# check equivalence of two vector, never mind order

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

suppose I have a number vectors, with one acting as a key:

```
key  <- c("A", "B")
vec1 <- c("B", "A")      #one that changes the order
vec2 <- c("A")           #one that is less one 
vec3 <- c("A", "B", "C") #one that is plus one
vec4 <- c("A", "B")      #this one is identical
```

I want the check to go as follows:

```
if(vec [has all the elements of] key == TRUE)
```

so, results would go:

```
vec1 == TRUE
vec2 == FALSE
vec3 == FALSE
vec4 == TRUE
```

I've tried `all()` but...

```
all(key %in% vec1)  #TRUE  (as hoped)
all(key %in% vec2)  #FALSE (as hoped)
all(key %in% vec3)  #TRUE  (drat!)
all(key %in% vec3)  #TRUE  (as expected)
```

I could get the job done with multiple conditions:

```
all(key %in% vec1) & all(vec1 %in% key) #TRUE
all(key %in% vec2) & all(vec2 %in% key) #FALSE
all(key %in% vec3) & all(vec3 %in% key) #FALSE
all(key %in% vec4) & all(vec4 %in% key) #TRUE
```

I was wondering if there was a more elegant way?

Comment: `setequal` assuming you don't have / care about repeated elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understood it correctly you could try `setequal(key, vec)`.

For your set of vectors above it would generate the below results:

```
> setequal(key, vec1)
[1] TRUE
> setequal(key, vec2)
[1] FALSE
> setequal(key, vec3)
[1] FALSE
> setequal(key, vec4)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make sorted versions of the key and each candidate vector, and compare the sorted versions.

Comment: Generally, it's good to provide some code to illustrate what you mean and that it works (on the OP's examples and maybe other edge cases).